# How can I use a local variable in an event listener?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, dom-events

My problem is with using the Google Maps API, but I'm pretty certain it is a general JavaScript problem.

I have a local array of objects defining a series of markers. Processing these objects is no problem. But I want to use one of the values in an event handler I create, and the value is always "undefined" by the time that event handler is called. (Which is logical, since the value was part of a local array, but I don't know how I can solve this.)

The code:

```
var markers = [
   { lat: 58, lng: 07, title: 'Marker 01', url: 'article.aspx' },
   .... /* etc */
]
for (var idx in markers) {
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({ 
    position: new google.maps.LatLng( markers[idx].lat, markers[idx].lng ), 
    title: markers[idx].title,
    map: map
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener( marker, 'click', function() {
    window.location.href = markers[idx].url;
  });
}
```

When I click on one of the markers in the final map (ie. trigger the 'click' listener), I am redirected to a page called 'undefined', because the 'url' attribute no longer has a value. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can pass the url to the function that is called into the addListener

Comment: Thanks! What I now did is this:

    (function(m,u){google.maps.event.addListener(m, 'click', function () { window.location.href = u; })})(marker,markers[idx].url);

And it works! Is this really the best way to solve it?

Comment: I think that can be better if you try to pass it to the other function (the one inside the addListener method)